# Where to buy the Logitech crayon for educational iPad use?

Tags: ios, ipad, apple-store, accessories, third-party

I bought the new 2018 iPad for my son and I want to buy the crayon as well.

Except that it's not available anywhere I’ve searched (Apple and Amazon) and the blogs say its only available via schools:

- https://www.geeky-gadgets.com/logitech-crayon-ipad-stylus-17-05-2018/

It’s not clear to me how can I buy this beautiful gadget. So should I send a note to my son's elementary school?

Comment: I see this as an exception to the rule about no shopping questions here since it’s widely touted and Apple doesn’t publish education channel details publicly and even if you have a business account, you can’t buy these in August 2018.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After September 12 the crayon for iPad will be for sale to the general public.

- https://news.logitech.com/press-release/consumer-products/unleash-creativity-logitech-crayon-exclusively-new-97-inch-ipad

Until then it’s still available in the initially exclusive education channel at Apple. That means someone in education needs to purchase it - not that you’d interact with the retail stores, retail app or any online channel as someone shopping the B2C or B2B sales channels.

- https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/crayon

> LOGITECH CRAYON All sales and samples are handled through the Apple
>   Education channel.
>
> • Contact your Apple Education rep for additional details
>   • Don’t know your rep? Call 1(800) 800 APPLE or find more info at 
>   [www.apple.com/education/purchasing](http://www.apple.com/education/purchasing)

More information is available [on pricing and dates where other retailers are expected to start carrying this accessory](https://9to5mac.com/2018/09/06/review-logitech-crayon-apple-pencil-alternative/).